# When did the snowflake data types start to be expressed in the local timezone instead of UTC?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When did the snowflake data types start to be expressed in the local timezone instead of UTC? Is this changed since 3.13.20? After snowflake-jdbc driver update from 3.12.17, I started to retrieve different values from TIME, TIMESTAMP_NTZ, TIMESTAMP_TZ and others. After the upgrade, it seems like, they are using local timezone offset.

Example:

```
               TIME            TIMESTAMP_NTZ             TIMESTAMP_TZ

3.12.17 22:46:42.000 +0000 2021-01-16 13:46:42.000 2021-01-16 22:46:42.123 +0000

3.12.20 22:46:42.000 +0100 2021-01-16 14:46:42.000 2021-01-16 15:46:42.000 +0100
```

The most strange change occured in TIMESTAMP_TZ type. Now I am getting -7 hours.

I've tried to upgrade the version to 3.13.32 and faced this problem. Can you explain me, what is the cause of this change, where can i find the info about it in release notes or in documentation?

Thanks

Comment: [Behavior Change Log](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Pending-Behavior-Change-Log) - `2021_01 Bundle - Ecosystem Changes - Snowflake JDBC Driver Version 3.12.17 and Later: Session Timezone Used for Returned Dates and Times`

Comment: Thanks, but there is written, that already in version 3.12.17 the timezone usage (JVM to session) has changed. So my question is, why the changes occured between 3.13.19 to 3.13.20. I just wanna say, that it is working until 3.13.20.

Comment: i think it may be - you are in UTC and the Snowflake default TZ is PST and you are getting 7hours of difference.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem because I have overridden the default TIMEZONE to UTC. And this value was set even before the change to the JDBC version. (3.12.17 → 3.13.32)